# Vue js How to split string to array and use in v-for list renderer

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, split, vuejs2

I want to split a row of a list and use the result in another list statement like this :
I actually know that the syntax of Vue list renderer of this type is incorrect but I want to show you what I need!

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el : "#app",
  data : {
    list : [
      {
        'name' : 'aaa',
        'codes' : '111+222+333'
      },
      {
        'name' : 'bbb',
        'codes' : '432+456+678'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="row in list">
    <p>{{ row.name }}</p>
    <div v-for="code in (row.codes.split('+'))">
      <p>{{ code }}</p>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** The above code is correct and I had some problems when using filters like this that **is wrong** :

```
v-for="code in (row.codes | split('+'))"
```

Comment: Your code will work as long as you (1) load VueJS library, (2) fix unclosed `<p>` and `<div>` elements, and (3) add the missing `})` at the end of your code. https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/k1L7p9hm/

Comment: wow! this is unbelievable but I didn't try this syntax. I actually used filters in for that was incorrect! thanks, Terry :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Here is my solution!

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="row in splitedList">
    <p>{{ row.name }}</p>
    <div v-for="code in row.codes">
      <p>{{ code }}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list : [
      {
        'name' : 'aaa',
        'codes' : '111+222+333'
      },
      {
        'name' : 'bbb',
        'codes' : '432+456+678'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    splitedList(){
        let newArr = [...this.list]
      newArr.map(el => {
        return el.codes = el.codes.split('+')
      })
      return newArr
    }
  }

})
```

*[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/47586/)*

Comment: yes, this a true solution but little complicated  :)

Comment: why complicated?it is very clear and simple in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

`v-for="code in row.codes.split('+')"`

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. consider editing to add explanation. Quality answers accrue the most upvotes over time as future visitors learn something to apply to their own code bases.

Answer (score 0):

I use in function in method...

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="row in list">
    <p>{{ row.name }}</p>
    <div v-for="code in splitedList(row.codes)">
      <p>{{ code }}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list : [
      {
        'name' : 'aaa',
        'codes' : '111+222+333'
      },
      {
        'name' : 'bbb',
        'codes' : '432+456+678'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
  },
methods: {  
    splitedList(row){               
              return (row !== null)?row.split('+'):'';
        }
    }

})
```